# SPICE C compiling issues

Tags: software, spice

I have been trying to run Spice in C code for one week but I have not succeeded. *I know how to use Spice in Matlab and Python* but I need to use it in C this time.

- I have followed this [tutorial](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/40_program_c.pdf) by JPL.
- I have dowloaded Cspice from [here](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit_C_PC_Linux_GCC_64bit.html).
- I am using Visual studio code with gcc to compile my C code and it works for other simple C scripts.
- I have downloaded the Cspice code in the folder C:\spicetest.
- I have downloaded the leapseconds kernel from [here](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/lsk/)  and I have put it in C:\spicetest\cspice\data.
- I have renamed *cspice.a* in C:\spicetest\cspice\lib as *libcspice.a* because gcc was giving me errors

This is my C code which I have called gyoza.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SpiceUsr.h"

int main()
{
    /*define variables*/
    SpiceDouble et;
    SpiceChar time[] = "2017-07-14T19:46:00";
    SpiceChar path[] = "C:\\spicetest\\cspice\\data\\naif0012.tls.pc";
    
    /* load kernels*/
    furnsh_c(path);

    /* spice function*/
    str2et_c( time, &et);
    
    /* print result*/
    printf("%f \n", et);
}
```

These are the compiling instruction I am using in Visual studio Code terminal:

`gcc -IC:\spicetest\cspice\include -o ramen gyoza.c -c -ansi -m64 -O2 -fPIC -DNON_UNIX_STDIO -LC:\spicetest\cspice\lib -lcspice -lm`

So ramen it is my output file, it should be an executable, but it is a binary file with no extension and I do not know how to run it.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Your file naming is making me hungry.   If you didn't get any errors, the output file is your executable.  `.\ramen` should execute it. If not, try `-o ramen.exe` instead, hoping that Windows will recognize it as executable (I haven't used Windows in while, to be honest...)

Comment: Lol. I have already tried both. If I do `.\ramen` it opens the binary file in notepad which is not readable. If I do `-o ramen.exe` it gives me this error: 


 Program 'ramen.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1
 + .\ramen       
 + ~~~~~~~.      
 At line:1 char:1
 + .\ramen
 + ~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: Maybe is it like a linux executable? Sorry but I am quite new to C compiling

Comment: The download link in the 2nd bullet points to a Linux version of the library. Are you sure you're using the Windows version? (You may have more luck getting a good answer on stackoverflow.com or superuser)

Comment: Yes I am using it because I use gcc  and not MS Visual C. But maybe that is the problem. Thank you very much. I will try also other websistes

Comment: This doesn't really belong here. Try a coding stack exchange. but great question.

Comment: The link in the question indicates you downloaded the Linux version. Download the Windows version instead. You may still run into issues because the CPSICE team uses a 2008 version of Visual Studios. If you have VS 2015 or later it won't work. The solution apparently is easy: Rebuild cspice.lib using the cspice\makeall.bat script. See https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit_install_problems for details.

Comment: Ok thanks. BTW I have also tried the WIndows version but with gcc it still does not work. If I resolve this problem I will post here a solution or a link to it

Comment: @DavidHammen I have tried what you said. I have downloaded the Windows Version of spice. Then I searched for vcvars32.bat file path in Visual Studio folders, I opened the path, ran vcvars32.bat so now cl is a recognized command. Then cd in spice folder and rebuilt the libraries with makeall.bat. I have checked that cl works with a simple c file. Then I have tried to compile my gyoza.c script but it gives me this warning: cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:\spicewin\cspice\lib\cspice.lib' ignored and it creates only a .obj file not an .exe as output

Comment: I have tried to use these cl options: `cl gyoza.c -IC:\spicewin\cspice\include  C:\spicewin\cspice\lib\cspice.lib` . And a more complete: `cl gyoza.c /IC:\spicewin\cspice\include /c /O2 -D_COMPLEX_DEFINED -DMSDOS -DNON_ANSI_STDIO  C:\spicewin\cspice\lib\cspice.lib C:\spicewin\cspice\lib\csupport.lib` . But I receive the same warning as mentioned above. Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited to stackoverflow than space exploration.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes maybe it is not the right place. BTW I have resolved thanks to the help of kind NASA engineers. If you would like I can post the solutiion

Comment: I have tried the same with no succeess. Can you describe how you managed to run Spice in C in Visual Studio? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @buzzlightyear Congratulations on your solution and Welcome to Space Exploration SE! It is always okay to post a (good) answer to your own question, especially if it solves a problem in a way that might be helpful to future readers who find your question when searching for answers. Please consider posting your answer. This site certainly carves out a niche of questions about issues with software specifically related to space exploration (e.g. SPICE, STK...) so your question was never closed.

Comment: Looks like this is a "I solved it" Google dead end.  Since it's been almost a year, the author isn't likely to post a solution, so this question should be removed if possible to avoid search engines directing people here.

Comment: @GregMiller without any answer I think the chances are low that google will send folks here, so it probably does not look like a google dead end

Comment: @uhoh, the post above your last one, and the reason this question popped back up, is exactly that case.

Comment: @GregMiller a screenshot of a google result, together with some demonstration of harm would make an excellent basis of a meta post calling attention to this. There is also the option of flagging it for moderator attention.